# mean of a continuous random variable and integration by parts

Tags: calculus

$g(t)= \ln(t)$ for $1\leq t \leq e$ is a PDF for a continuous random variable $T$. find the mean of $T$ using the definition of the mean of a continuous random variable and then performing integration by parts.

I don't seem to understand how to do this?

Comment: What don't you understand about this question? Do you understand how to calculate the mean of a random variable given its PDF? Have you got an expression for this?

Answer (score 1):

$\int_1^e t\ln(t)dt$

This is a canonical integration by parts problem

Comment: I am not sure how to integrate it

Comment: https://www.integral-calculator.com/

This has a step by step solution. For more in depth information, look here:

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Prototank says, this is a canon IBP. Set $u = \ln t$ and $dv = t \ dt$. Can you go from here?

Comment: Don't exactly know how to go on from here

Comment: The integration by parts formula is $\int_a ^b u \ dv = u(b)v(b) - u(a)v(a) - \int_a ^b v \ du$. If you're still stuck, review your calculus II notes or the page suggested above.